# Writing recursive functions

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion

I'm having trouble with writing recursive functions.

The triangular numbers are as follows:

1 = 1

3 = 1 + 2

6 = 1 + 2 + 3

10 = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4

15 = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5

21 = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6

etc.

The series begins with 1 (the first triangular number). To calculate the nth triangular number, n is
added to the previous triangular number. For example, the fourth triangular number is calculated
by adding 4 to the third triangular number (which is 6), i.e. 10 = (1 + 2 + 3) + 4.

So far, this is what I've come up with:

```
int triNum(n)
{
    if (n<=1)
        return n;

    int num = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        num = n + triNum(n-1)
    }
    return num;
}
```

However I'm not sure that this is the correct answer, can anyone help guide me how I should approach this problem?

Comment: Have you *tested* your code? Does it work for your test-cases?

Comment: I would take a look at what happens in that for loop.

Comment: An aside: the nth triangle number can be computed directly: `n*(n+1)/2`

Comment: the posted code does not perform the desired functionality.  Suggest replacing the `for()` loop with a simple statement: `return = n + triNum(n-1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here this produces the desired output:

```
int tri(int n) {
    if (n < 1) return 1;
    return (n+1) + tri(n-1);
}
```

You can test it like this:

```
int main(void){
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        printf("%d: %d\n",i,tri(i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @sidyll why is that?

Comment: The definition should be _n + tri(n-1)_ unless you want it to be off by one. And you ignored the 0th triangular number, which is 0.

Comment: Idk in his definition the first triangular number is 1, so I started the sequence  off by that (starting from 0). My code produces the correct results, but you can submit a different answer if you think this one is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For recursive calls, you need to know the formula from n-1 to n. In your case `f(n) = n + f(n-1)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int triangular(int n) {
    if (n == 1)
        return 1;
    return n + triangular(n-1)
}
```

Let the `n`-th triangular number be represented by the function `f(n)`. So, now we need to find a way to relate this state of the function to the previous states, where a state is represented by the argument of the function `f`. We notice that if we know the `(n-1)`-th triangular number, we can find the `n`-th with the formula `f(n) = n + f(n-1)`. With this we stated the function f recursively, i.e, we calculate a state of the function using it's previous states(in this case its only one previous state, `f(n-1)`). The implementation is straightforward. If you still don't understand the implementation, try to draw the recursion with a graph and you'll see why it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need the loop. It's not an iterative process, instead it's a recursive implementation. The answer lies in your text:

> For example, the fourth triangular number is calculated by adding 4 to the third triangular number

Generalising, the *n*th (4th) triangular is calculated by adding *n* (4) to the triangular of *n-1* (3).

```
int triNum(n)
{
    if (n<=1)
        return n;

    int num = 0;

    num = n + triNum(n-1)

    return num;
}
```

Which can be simplified to:

```
unsigned int
triNum(unsigned int n)
{
    if (n <= 1) return n;
    return n + triNum(n-1);
}
```