# Program a triangle number (sum of an arithmetic progression) without using iterations

Tags: java

The basic idea of the question is:

A triangle number is the sum of an arithmetic progression,
i.e `1,3,6,10,15..etc.` 
(arrived at this as: `1+0,1+2,1+2+3, 1+2+3+4, 1+2+3+4+5... etc`)

I've coded the following question using iterations, how do I do it without it?

```
public class Test {
    static int triangle(int n) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < n + 1; index++) {
        total = total + index;
    }
    return total;
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    for (int x = 1; x < 6; x++)
        System.out.println(triangle(x));
    }
}
```

The output is correct, but I want a better solution then what I have written.

The O/P:

```
1
3
6
10
15
```

Comment: Ask yourself how each number in the progression is related to it's position.  i.e.  Position `5` gives the result `15`.  What formula could you use to get from 5 to 15 that works for all other positions.  (And it's not 3 x n)

Comment: Hint: you need to use recursion.

Comment: @StephenC Or just an explicit formula, as already stated by Tibrogargan above.

Comment: Well yea ... but I don't think that is what Mike's teacher wants.

Comment: just simply static int triangle(int n) {return ( n *  (n + 1)) / 2}

Comment: @StephenC sir, while saying recursion, *I hope* you don't only wish it to iterate over.

Comment: @snr - I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: @StephenC recursion is a form of iteration.  The class the OP is taking is probably a computational statistics or calculus intro subject.  `(n^2 + n)/2` is pretty easy

Comment: (Iteration is a form of recursion, and vice versa.  If you hold your mouth correctly.  That's beside the point.) If the OP was taking a math-based subject, they would expect the OP to know the simple formula, and wouldn't set an exercise this trivial.  I think he is a beginner IT student an they are trying to get him to understand how to rewrite a loop with recursion.  Unfortunately, the OP didn't express himself (or herself) clearly, either because of poor English skills, or lack of basic programming knowledge.

Comment: Add to that that the OP has **accepted** an answer that presents a recursive solution rather than one that (just) solves the problem using the formula.

Comment: But either way, since the OP has not taken the time to clarify this, it would be best to either find a dup (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46900419/writing-recursive-functions) or close the Question as a "unclear" or "too broad".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using recursion:

```
public static void triangular(int start, int n){
    if(start > n)
        return;
    int triangular = (start*(start+1))/2;
    System.out.println(triangular);
    triangular(start+1,n);
}
```

Usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int n = 5;
    triangular(1,n);
}
```

> OUTPUT: 1 3 6 10 15

Triangular number of any number n is = `(n*(n+1))/2`. so for n=5, its triangular number is 15. Using this formula i applied recursion.

Comment: It's technically recursion. Yet, it doesn't yield a solution striking a note (:

Comment: @snr can u be more explicit?

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you can exploit is the fact that each number `i` in your sequence is the sum of numbers in the series `1...i`.

So each number in your sequence can be computed using `n(n+1)/2`. Therefore:

```
static int triangle(int n) {
    return (n * (n + 1)) / 2;
}
```

And you can just use this easy int stream (use a loop if preferred):

```
IntStream.range(1, 10).map(Main::sumAt).forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

Which outputs (you just choose where your int stream stops):

```
1
3
6
10
15
21
28
36
45
```

Comment: streams are also iterations behind the scenes, no?

Comment: @Mustahsan `triangle(int n)` in this answer does not use iteration (that's what the OP didn't want) - that's why I have the *use a loop if preferred* note there

Comment: that's good for getting 1 number but i think he wants whole series without using any iteration

Answer (score 0):

You can replace iteration by recursion

```
public class Test {
 static int triangle(int n) {
  return n <= 1 ? 1 : n+triangle(n-1);
 }
}
```

But that will not be better for performances
If the objective is to increase performances, i'm sorry but we need to use the most obscure power on earth, the mathematics !!!

Comment: he will need to call this method in a loop as well?

Comment: Not at ald just call the he could just call triangle(3) and get 6 as output. The loop is hidden in the recursion.

Comment: but he will not get the whole series he wants, he doesnt want a single number so

Comment: As @Mustahsan stated I need the whole series, not an individual number.

Comment: @Mike did you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56556102/9722122 ?

Answer (score 0):

One way to think about this problem is this:

> To calculate the nth triangle number, you first need to calculate the (n-1)th triangle number. Then add n to that number. Also, the first triangular number is 1.

Now you can just put this in code, and you are done:

```
static int triangle(int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    return n + triangle(n - 1);
}
```

Alternatively, the nth triangle numbers is also the sum of the first n terms of the arithmetic sequence 1,2,3,4,5... This means that we can use the formula for the sum of first n terms of an arithmetic sequence to solve this problem as well.

```
n * (2 * a + (n - 1) * d) / 2
```

Substituting the common difference d as 1, and the first term a as 1, we get

```
n * (n + 1) / 2
```

So we can just write the method as:

```
static int triangle(int n) {
    return n * (n + 1) / 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hold previous sum and add to current number

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
            int tNumber = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i <=10 ; i++) {
                tNumber=tNumber+i;
                System.out.print(" "+tNumber);
            }
```

Output:

```
 1 3 6 10 15 21 28 36 45 55
```

Answer (score 0):

Obtaining a sequence is inevitably impossible without a loop or recursion. However, to calculate an element of the sequence can be done with/without it.

There are a ton of formula to achieve it. The following code involves both recursion and without iteration solution.

```
class Sol {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(f(5));
        System.out.println(f2(5));
    }

    public static int f(int n) {
        return (int)(n - Math.floor(n/2) +
                Math.floor(n*n/2));
    }

    public static int f2(int n) {
        if (n <= 0)
            return 0;
        if (n <= 1)
            return 1;

        return 3* f2(n-1) - 3* f2(n-2) + f2(n-3);
    }
}
```

Comment: while this is a good solution for individual number, I need the whole series, not an individual number. I do understand your outlook on the question though, it helps.

Comment: @Mike in the life every thing has a limit. So, you cannot obtain whole series, but until a point.